# How to check if file pointers/descriptors/handles are associated to the same file/pipe/terminal?

Tags: python, c++, io-redirection, buffering

File content will be messed up if `stdout` and `stderr` are full-buffered and redirected to the same file by the shell.

Are there ways to check whether the underlying files/pipes/terminals of file pointers/descriptors/handles are the same in C++ and Python?

Buffering should be disabled only if `stdout` and `stderr` are redirected to the same file.

EDIT:
Thanks for [isedev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321889/how-to-check-if-file-pointers-descriptors-handles-are-associated-to-the-same-fil#comment60267088_36321889).

That idea also works in Python 3.4.

```
def same_file(file1, file2):
    stat1, stat2 = os.fstat(file1.fileno()), os.fstat(file2.fileno())
    return (stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev) and (stat1.st_ino == stat2.st_ino)
```

This doesn't work for pipe/terminal of course.

[Similar way to check for the same file in WinAPI](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/195).

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502552/can-i-check-if-two-file-or-file-descriptor-numbers-refer-to-the-same-file

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard way to determine what an FD actually refers to. It's also possible to have multiple FDs refer to the same file, which is what happens when the `dup(2)` family of functions are used.

Also see [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)